# How do I pass data from <layout> in <template> to a method in my export default in Vue?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, vue.js

I'm trying to collect the text from a text input in HTML to the methods section of my Vue file but can't seem to figure it out. I've spent a couple hours researching v-model and messing around with it but, I was either doing it wrong or it doesn't do what I thought it did. Here's my code:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Layout>
      <input id="queryBox" placeholder="Enter your SQL query here." size="60"/>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" v-on:click="logSomething()">
    </Layout>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => {
      return {
        queryText: ""
      }
    },
    methods: {
      logSomething() {
        console.log(this.queryBox)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I'm trying to send whatever the user inputs into queryBox to the logSomething() method upon the click of the submit button. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the v-model and map your `queryText` variable that will contain your input field data. And then on click, use the event and make the submit not to load form, just to avoid load page.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Layout>
      <input id="queryBox" v-model="queryText" placeholder="Enter your SQL query here." size="60"/>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" v-on:click="logSomething">
    </Layout>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => {
      return {
        queryText: ""
      }
    },
    methods: {
      logSomething(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.queryText)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```